# Cache with multiple keys and reading with a single one

Tags: java, caching, data-structures, guava

Seems like this is a quite common case, but did not find any solutions to it yet.

Following scenario: I need to implement a cache (may be based on e.g. Guava or so), that stores objects in memory. The object I store is identifiable by either one of following:

```
(id)
(propA, propB, propC)
```

So it is either the ID or a combination of three properties. Now, I can of course store this to a cache with a combined key (some easy java class, or Pair):

```
[(id), (propA, propB, propC)] -> (object)
```

So far, this is nothing special. My problem is, that during reading of the cache, I only have  either one of the keys. So calculating `hashCode()` on the combined key fails to hit the cache entry.

For now, I have one solution in mind, which are basically two caches/maps:

```
(propA, propB, propC) -> (id)
(id) -> (object)
```

Does someone know an alternative way to achieve this, or is maybe even aware of existing implementations for such cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, we're using something similar to the solution you're thinking of. If you want to use Guava's loading cache then cache misses might be a problem though: if you don't get an id for your properties then you don't know what to feed to the loader. Thus you'd need to handle the loading yourself. One thing we do to handle cache misses: we use optionals to distinguish between entries that don't exist (we've tried to load them) or that haven't been requested yet.

Comment: Why not use which ever key is available at the time of entry into the cache.  If you end up caching under both keys...who cares.

Comment: @BrentR, but is that easy in Java?

Comment: I'm curious, how big is the cache? If not too big, an in-process full scan could be an option.

Comment: The two caches idea will work, but you'll need a mapping from `{id}` to `(propA, propB, propC)` so that when somebody adds or removes an item by `{id}`, you can add or remove the corresponding entry in the other hash map.